# Windows Server 2008 stopped showing progress of installing updates after emergency reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I had to reboot machine with w2k8 server by pressing "reset" during it was installing updates due to hung update. After this when I've rebooted and resumed update process it installs update but does not show usual messages like "Installing update X of Y" and name of update, and progress bar also does not show progress. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reboot in safe mode and uninstall recent updates
2. Check logs in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution directory, also clean Downloads there.
3. Reboot and try to install updates once more

Answer (score 0):

Does the system event log show any windows update specific error messages?
Have you restarted the server after it completed installing the rest of the updates?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've encountered some bugs in the update process.  Whether and how update progress is displayed is not configurable and there isn't anything you can likely do to change it.  It's also not something that would typically be considered a problem that needs solving.

Answer (score 0):

The solution helped me

```
1. Start elevated shell
2. net stop wuauserv
3. rmdir /S /Q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistrubution
4. net start wuauserv
```

Then go to Windows Updated and check updates.